# How would you parenthetically cite an author that appears twice in a works cited page? MLA

Tags: ambiguity, mla

How would you parenthetically cite an author that appears twice in a works cited page? 
I would like to cite Wachs. Here is a piece of my works cited:

Wachs, Juan, Helman Stern, Yael Edan, Michael Gillam, Craig Feied, Mark Smith, and Jon                                          Handler. Gestix: A Doctor-Computer Sterile Gesture Interface for Dynamic Environments. Tech. Web. 21 Mar. 2012.

Wachs, Juan, Yu-Ting Li, and Mithun Jacob. "Gestonurse." Gestonurse. Purdue University Industrial Engineering Lab., 2012. Web. 21 Mar. 2012.

Assuming that I would like to parenthetically cite the second source, how would I go about doing this to differentiate from the first source?

Comment: In the future, [writers.se] is probably the right place to ask questions like this. (See also http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/1423/13812.)

Comment: For the benefit of writersSE, this post may be migrated there. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: This question should be migrated to Writers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Purdue Online Writing Lab](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/), when using the MLA format you would distinguish multiple works by the same author by including a shortened version of the title of the particular reference that you are citing. Thus your examples might appear as follows (where 'p.' indicates the page number/s, which should also be included):

> (Wachs, *Gestix* p.)

and

> (Wachs, *Gestonurse* p.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I greatly appreciate the time and effort!

Comment: Glad you liked it! The other answer (and comments) is perfectly valid but (as far as I can tell) not standard for MLA. I myself prefer author-year (eg Smith 2001b), but that's Harvard system.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to number your references. Then you can just have Wachs[1] versus Wachs[2], and in the references:

1. Wachs, Juan, Helman Stern, Yael Edan, Michael Gillam, Craig Feied, Mark Smith, and Jon Handler. Gestix: A Doctor-Computer Sterile Gesture Interface for Dynamic Environments. Tech. Web. 21 Mar. 2012.
2. Wachs, Juan, Yu-Ting Li, and Mithun Jacob. "Gestonurse." Gestonurse. Purdue University Industrial Engineering Lab., 2012. Web. 21 Mar. 2012.

Of course these two could actually be 13 and 14 or whatever.

Comment: That's okay. P.S. there are other schemes. One is to use years, like Smith [1983] and Smith [1989]. This is good if you're doing citations manually: the years are not moving targets in any way. If you insert something, there is no renumbering. Unfortunately, it doesn't work out very well here because your little ego-maniac published two things on the same date. :)

Comment: Then use year **and** serial#.